# What files are being compared in a git diff?

Tags: git

According to the book ***Version Control with Git***, "git diff shows the difference between your working directory and the index. It exposes what is dirty in your working directory and is thus a candidate to stage for your next commit."

What does "git diff shows the difference between your working directory and the index" mean? When you modify a file and run git diff, there's nothing in the staging area for git to compare the working directory to since you haven't staged anything yet so what is it comparing it to?

Comment: The index doesn't contain "nothing", it contains the contents of the repository in the state of the lastest commit.

Comment: How is it different from comparing to the last commit using git diff HEAD?

Comment: It isn't different until you modify the index.

Comment: Maybe this helps your understanding: https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_examples

Comment: I understand git diff shows what has changed but not yet staged but I don't understand how it is the same as saying it compares what is in the working directory to what is in the staging area.

Comment: If I don't git add anything and run git diff after a file modification, it shows me changes. What are the two things being compared here? I don't get it. Also I'm new to git. Just started learning it so a simple explanation would be helpful.

Comment: It may help to think of the index as containing a *copy of the proposed next commit*.  (It does in fact contain such a copy, though it has even more than that in it.) Git sometimes uses the phrase "empty" for this, but the index is rarely actually *empty*; it's just usually *the same* as the `HEAD` commit, when you start out. Hence, when you start out, there are *three* copies of every file: the permanent one in `HEAD`, the proposed one in the index, and the easy-to-work-with one in the work-tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your repository *state* is clean, meaning you have not yet modified any file, then the index matches the state of the repository at the commit HEAD points to.

In this case, if you modify a file and then do a `git diff`, the modified file (in your working area) will be compared against the index, which will show the same differences as if you compared it against the current commit.

However, if you now stage that file (`git add that-file`), then modify it again, and do another `git diff`, your modified file (in your working area) will be compared against the staged and modified file in the index. This will now be different from comparing against the HEAD commit.

If you run these commands you will see that `git diff` compares b with c, not a with c:

```
git init .

echo a >test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

echo b >test.txt
git add .

echo c >test.txt
git diff
```

Output:

```
diff --git i/test.txt w/test.txt
index 2fea07c..12d6973 100644
--- i/test.txt
+++ w/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-b 
+c
```